# Error when using the Domain Access module

Tags: domain-access

I installed the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module and get the following error:

> Domain access failed to load during phase: bootstrap include. Please check your settings.php file and site configuration.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you read the installation instructions bundled with the module?

Comment: You're going to have to read the README.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the readme file [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/domain.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/INSTALL.txt).

There is also a quickstart version [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/domain.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/INSTALL_QUICKSTART.txt).

The main bit you will need is the following (taken from the [quickstart](http://drupalcode.org/project/domain.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/INSTALL_QUICKSTART.txt) version - line 24):

> Add the following four lines of code to your settings.php file:
>
> > /**
> >     * Add the domain module setup routine.
> >     */
> >     include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';
>
> NOTE: You may need to alter the file path above based on your
>        site configuration.  See INSTALL.txt for further help.
>
> IMPORTANT: You must add these lines to settings.php after the
>        $databases. Normally, you should add these lines to the end of the
>        settings.php file.
>
> NOTE: If you perform a Drupal core version upgrade, you must
>        remove these lines from settings.php.  See UPGRADE.txt for details.

Answer (score 0):

"Domain access failed to load during phase: bootstrap include. Please check your settings.php file and site configuration."

Solution was the following:
you need to add the 4 line to the settings.php file, right?
But, to do it, you need to set the 'default' folder permission to '777'
After this, you can delete the settings.php... upload the new one, which includes this:
/**
 * Add the domain module setup routine.
 */
include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc

at the bottom of the file.
Changed the permission back to '555' and thats it...
Enjoy!